# Gaussian elimination number of iteration

Tags: linear-algebra

If $ A $ is an $ n \times n $ matrix and suppose we want to solve $ Ax = b $ using Gaussian elimination. The runtime complexity for Gaussian elimination is $ O(n^3), $ but what is the approximate number of iterations required to perform the algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you call an iteration.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computational_efficiency) says

> The number of arithmetic operations required to perform row reduction is one way of measuring the algorithm's computational efficiency. For example, to solve a system of $n$ equations for $n$ unknowns by performing row operations on the matrix until it is in echelon form, and then solving for each unknown in reverse order, requires $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ divisions, $\frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 − 5n}{6}$ multiplications, and $\frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 − 5n}{6}$ subtractions, for a total of approximately $\frac{2n^3}{3}$ operations.

Answer (score 0):

It indeed does depend on what you consider an iteration because because an iteration can be 1) reduce the rest of the sub-matrix, 2) reduce the following row, or 3) reduce the current matrix element.

If an "iteration" is reducing a single row, then there are $(n-1) + (n - 2) + (n - 3)... \approx O(n^2)$ iterations.  If an iteration is reducing a sub-matrix then there are $n - 1 \approx O(n)$.